# Calculate remaining seconds in php

Tags: php, date, time, seconds

I have this code:

```
$d = ($subTime/(60*60*24))%365;
$h = ($subTime/(60*60))%24;
$m = ($subTime/60)%60;
$s = ($subTime);

echo $d." days\n";
echo $h." hours\n";
echo $m." minutes\n";
echo $s." seconds\n";
```

It echoes: 90 days 0 hours 32 minutes 7777955 seconds

Is there a formula that instead of 7777955 seconds to display from 1 to 60?

Comment: `$s = $subTime - ($d*86400) - ($h*3600) - ($m*60);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use modulo for this as well:

```
$s = $subtime % 60;
```